# Position popup on left of screen mobile devices

Tags: jquery

The code below works OK on desktop, but the problem I have is on mobile devices when the button is near the right of the screen, the popup appears under the button, but you need to scroll to the right to see it.

I cannot work out how to move the popup to the left on mobile devices

```
$('#btnMetal').on("click",
        function() {
            $("#metalList").css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'z-index': '99',
                'left': $(this).offset().left,
                'top': $(this).offset().top + $(this).height() + 5
            }).slideToggle().delay(1000);
        });
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this

----------HTML For button

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                <span class="item-types">
                    <button id="btnStyle">Style <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></button>
                </span>
                <span class="item-types">
                    <button id="btnMetal">Metal <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></button>
                </span>
                <span class="item-types">
                    <button id="btnSort">Sort <i class="icon ion-ios-arrow-down"></i></button>
                </span>
        </div>
```

DIV

```
<div id="metalList">
    <div>
        <label class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" name="HighLow" class="chkSort" id="hl" value="hl">Cost High - Low
            <i class="helper"></i>
        </label>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#styleList, #diamondList, #metalList, #sortorder {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    max-width: 270px;
}
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML/CSS as well? It is hard to work with JS without any context.

Comment: I've added some HTML

Comment: As far as I can tell your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/5vzcnqeu/2/

Comment: Thanks, when I test it my popup appears of the screen and I need to scroll right to see it

Comment: Still not sure where the problem lies, here you have a screen shot for very narrow screen width and it's looking ok https://imgur.com/USz6NY2
There is no scroll bar what so ever.